# uitableview detail view programmatically

Tags: ios, ios8

Am new to objective c,I need to display the Json response in uitableview cell programmatically.And onclick of particular row display its details in next page in table view cell.please give some info regarding this.

Comment: Google for a tutorial, there are many

Comment: did you able to go the detail view? or yet not able to do this

Comment: Actually am able to move to detail view page but unable to display the corresponding data in detail view which I have selected in uitableview cell

Comment: You have to pass corresponding to details screen using NSDictonary or NSArray

Answer (score 0):

if You are using **storyboard**, you can implement this way.

Implement bellow line in  your **DetailViewController.h** file.

@property (strong, nonatomic) id **responseData**;

Then implement bellow method

```
 -(void)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController *eventDetailsViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
eventDetailsViewController.responseData = YourResponseData;//pass response data to detail view
[self.navigationController pushViewController:eventDetailsViewController animated:YES];

}
```